# How do I unlock the corner maps in Gemcraft Labyrinth?

Tags: gemcraft-labyrinth

I've completed the main mission in Gemcraft Labyrinth and unlocked the first of the 4 corner maps along the way - the other 3 remain stubbornly unavailable. Does anyone know what is required to open them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Kongregate forum FAQ thread](http://www.kongregate.com/forums/76-gemcraft-labyrinth/topics/168171-faqs-please-read-before-posting) states that the corner maps are unlocked by earning the following amulets:

> **A1**: L9 Challenge Amulet (Kill 7000 monsters)
> **A13**: Kill 12 Apparitions Amulet
> **M1**: Kill 200,000 monsters Amulet
> **M13**: K9 Challenge Amulet (complete 100 waves)
>
> Note that K9 challenge is not achievable with non-premium, and thus M13 is not unlockable.